# Object instantiation through factory method not giving desire result

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory

In below code snippet I do require to instantiate the object through factory  method in order to call the selected adapter (i.e. `adapterTwovalue`)but while calling through factory method i am not able to get the desire results. When we assign static declared object's address (i.e `adapter = &at`) it works but with factory i usually get the blank output.
I tried as well with (`adapter = new adapterTwo()`) to instantiate the object but output string is giving blank results. As per my requirement i need to populate the all the getters in `connect` function which is pure virtual function to frame the response.Anybody can suggest how to achieve this using factory method.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class IAdapter
    {
    public:
        enum FactoryList { AdapterOnevalue = 0, AdapterTwovalue };
        virtual void connect() = 0;
        static IAdapter* CreateList(FactoryList);
        virtual ~IAdapter() {}
    };

    class LibraryOne
    {
        string property;
    public:

        void SetConnection(string property)
        {
            this->property = property;
        }

        string getConnection()const
        {
            return property;
        }

    };

    //LibraryTwo
    class LibraryTwo
    {
        string broker;
    public:
        void SetBroker(string broker1)
        {
            this->broker = broker1;

        }

        string getBroker() const
        {       
            return broker;
        }


    };
    //adapterOne
    class AdapterOne : public IAdapter
    {
        LibraryOne one;
        string constring;
    public:

        void SetClientconnection(string constring)
        {
            one.SetConnection(constring);

        }

        string GetClientconnection()
        {

            return one.getConnection();

        }


        void connect()
        {

            constring = GetClientconnection();

        }
    };


    //Adapter to use library two
    class AdapterTwo : public IAdapter
    {
        LibraryTwo two;
        string brokerstring;
    public:

        void SetClientbroker(string constring)
        {
            two.SetBroker(constring);

        }

        string GetClientbroker()
        {

            return two.getBroker();

        }

        void connect()
        {

            string constring = GetClientbroker();
            cout << "final value=" << constring;

        }
    };

    IAdapter* IAdapter::CreateList(FactoryList SelectList)
    {
        IAdapter *ListObject;

        switch (SelectList)
        {
        case AdapterOnevalue:

            ListObject = new  AdapterOne();
            break;
        case AdapterTwovalue:
            ListObject = new AdapterTwo();

            break;
        default:
            ListObject = NULL;

        }

        return ListObject;

    }

    int main()
    {
        IAdapter *adapter = 0;
        //LibraryTwo obj;
        AdapterTwo at;
        at.SetClientbroker("amqp");
        //cout << at.GetClientbroker();
        //adapter = &at;   it works 
        adapter = IAdapter::CreateList(IAdapter::AdapterTwovalue);//it doesn't work
        //Just do the operation now
        adapter->connect();

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Does the `IAdapter::CreateList` method return a null pointer?

Comment: Do you want adapters to be singletons?

Comment: No it returns proper pointer  but as i mentioned in my question string output is coming blank only. it should print amqp .

Comment: @user2907032, what output did you expect to see?

Comment: Not related, but you should prefer C++ *keywords* over old (now obsolete) *macros*, so prefer `nullptr` over `NULL`...

Comment: You have never set the client broker at `adapter`, only at `at`...

Comment: SetClientbroker("amqp") method is responsible for setting the client broker and it is already being set in main function.

Comment: Since the factory creates a new instance, the property you have set in the first instance is obviously not set in the instance created with the factory. If you require the instance created by the factory to have its members set, you would need to pass these values to the factory.

Comment: I can't modify IAdaptor class and factory will only return the selected adapter objects.

Comment: Unrelated as well: prefer giving the parameter of `createList` function a name already in the declaration. Unnamed parameters signal to the *user* of your library/header that the parameter is not used in the function (Why then provide it at all??? 1. we might be overriding a function inherited from a base class 2. we might want/need to be compatible to an older version of the library where the function yet needed the parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the complete solution in below share link.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8b9d32a1fa989c9

Here is the explanation.

(1) setClientBroker() or all other adapters related  setter functionality needs to be implement as a virtual function in Interface with default parameter value " " (blank string).

(2) you need to always use override keyword (c++11) feature in derive class for setters  so that compiler will cross check during compilation whether proper virtual method is being overridden or not.

(3) instead of using local raw pointer , always use smart pointer . below is the 
    implementation link for the same.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2feea991ee90d4a2

Answer (score 1):

With your code I expect the output: `final value=`.

It will not print `final value=amqp` cause you need to call `SetClientbroker("amqp")` on the right adapter object (`adapter` in your example).

Anyway, I would think about putting a virtual method `SetString` in the base class, so you could simply do:

```
int main()
{
    IAdapter *adapter = 0;
    //LibraryTwo obj;
    //AdapterTwo at;
    //at.SetClientbroker("amqp");
    //cout << at.GetClientbroker();
    //adapter = &at;   it works 
    adapter = IAdapter::CreateList(IAdapter::AdapterTwovalue);//it doesn't work
    //Just do the operation now

    adapter->SetString("amqp");//<---------

    adapter->connect();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT after the comment:

You need to cast the object, at this point (as suggested by @Aconcagua).
But IMHO it's not elegant at all. I think you are going to loose the benefits gained with the factory method.

Comment: Base class modification is not allowed as it can have factory method only with pure virtual functions as it is being used as a abstract class there so it can't have any supportive method. apart from this  properties can be set through actual class only . so here are two design principles.  (1) software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification"  (2) one class must have only one responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
IAdapter* adapter = nullptr;
AdapterTwo at;
adapter = IAdapter::CreateList(IAdapter::AdapterTwovalue);
```

You have created two *independent* objects here (as calling `new` within `createList`): `at` and the one `adapter` points to.

```
AdapterTwo at;
at.SetClientbroker("amqp");
```

Now sure you get the expected output if you let `adapter` point to `at`, but how could the *other* object be aware of the string you set in the first one?

```
adapter = IAdapter::CreateList(IAdapter::AdapterTwovalue);
adapter->SetClientbroker("amqp"); // (*) !!!
```

You need to set the broker at the other object, too. As being different objects, you even can set the brokers independently:

```
AdapterTwo at;
at.SetClientbroker("amqp");
IAdapter* adapter = IAdapter::CreateList(IAdapter::AdapterTwovalue);
adapter->SetClientbroker("aconcagua"); // (*) !!!
```

Output now would be (if you called `connect` on both objects):

```
final value=amqp
final value=aconcagua
```

Only: The marked lines (`(*)`) *won't* compile as your base class does not provide the appropriate setter!

There are now different solutions for this problem. You could, for instance, just cast the object:

```
// if you are REALLY 100% sure the object is of appropriate type:
static_cast<AdapterTwo*>(adapter)->setClientBroker("...");

// if NOT:
AdapterTwo* a2 = dynamic_cast<AdapterTwo*>(adapter);
if(a2)
    a2->setClientBroker("...");
else
    // appropriate error handling
```

You could find a more generic name for the set/get Broker/ClientConnection functions, have them already pure virtual within `IAdapter` and *override* them in the two implementing adapter classes, so you could then just call `adapter->setXYZ("ampq");`. <sub>*[Edit: according to your comment to the question, not an option in the given case]*</sub>

My personal favourite is providing an additional parameter to your `createList` function such that the setter would already be called within the factory - possibly with appropriate default: empty string, if you opt for a `std::string` parameter, or `nullptr` in case of `char const*`. You'd only call the setter if the parameter is not matching the default, of course... Alternatively, you could have two overloads.